# Python >>> Appearing when it must be not

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, input

I have this code

```
 msg = input(">")
```

So I am expecting that when I run the code, it must wait for the users input and the appearance must be something like this:

```
>
```

But why does everytime I run the code, >>> appears.

```
>
>>>
```

[image]

Comment: >>> is the marker for the Python interactive shell's prompt. How are you running your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IDLE you will get `>>>` because it is the marker of Python Shell. I think you are using a new file to create your script and then you run it in the Python shell so you get `>>>` of your Python shell and then `>` of your `input`.